# how to create a new window using the CWindowImpl class

Tags: c++, winapi, atl

im trying to build a new window using the following class.
however im having some serious problems while trying to get the new generated window's name using the CWindow::m_hwnd variable. my guess is that i should pass a variable to the CWindowImpl::Create() function that holds my parent's HWND but i dont know how to get it.

```
STDMETHODIMP CVMNExporter::SetSite(IUnknown *pUnkSite) {
    HRESULT hr;
    if(FAILED(hr = ATL::IObjectWithSiteImpl<CVMNExporter>::SetSite(pUnkSite)))
        return hr;
    // We are rnning from a web browser
    CONNECTION_CALLBACK = JSCRIPT_DISPID;
    EXPORTING_CALLBACK  = JSCRIPT_DISPID;
    MERGING_CALLBACK    = JSCRIPT_DISPID;
    ABORTING_CALLBACK   = JSCRIPT_DISPID;

    AddRef();
    if(NULL == Create(0)) {// Creates the hidden window
        Release();
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
    }
    ATLTRACE("TEST - SetSite(): this: %d, window: %d", this, m_hWnd);
    m_dwApartmentMode = HWND_APARTMENT;
    SendMessage(WM_EXPORTER_APARTMENT_SETUP, 0, 0);
    return S_OK;  }
```

CVMNExporter implements the following interfaces:

```
        public ATL::IObjectSafetyImpl<CVMNExporter, INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CALLER | INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_DATA>,
        public ATL::IObjectWithSiteImpl<CVMNExporter>,
        public ATL::CWindowImpl<CVMNExporter, ATL::CWindow, ATL::CFrameWinTraits>,
```

thanks!

Comment: `CWindowImpl::Create` creates you the window and you are going to have your `HWND` available since there. If you want to provide parent window handle, you need to first obtain it from your site. You will need to query it using `IOleWindow::GetWindow` or similar method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it took me some time, but managed to solve it by using GetActiveWindow()